# Android Studio Java Google Sheets

Tags: java, android-studio, getresource

I'm facing a problem with connection to Google sheets via my `credentials.json` file (that was created for Android app). I simply can't read file in Android studio, but can read it in IntelliJ. Here on the images. I just want to understand what I'm doing wrong.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGG5o.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfFYE.png)

I used the simple code in both programm:

```
package org.example;

public class NewClass {
public static void execute() {
    System.out.println(NewClass.class
            .getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json"));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {execute();}
}
```

I've read many posts about this problem. But still I got this error and I don't understand why.

Comment: no screenshots of code. Post the code as text.